# Failed to execute goal on project..Could not resolve dependencies for

Tags: eclipse, maven, build

eclipse build failed and i got like this:-

Failed to execute goal on project : Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ericsson:JCA-CA-SADM:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6 -> org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6 -> org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-2: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon:pom:1.0-beta-2 from/to public (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Access denied to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon/1.0-beta-2/wagon-1.0-beta-2.pom. Error code 403, Forbidden -> [Help 1]

this is my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<!-- <parent> <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId> <artifactId>ca</artifactId> 
    <version>1.0.87-SNAPSHOT</version> <relativePath>../..</relativePath> </parent> -->

<parent>
    <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
    <artifactId>ca</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.125</version>
    <relativePath>../..</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>JCA-CA-SADM</artifactId>
<name>JCA-CA-SADM</name>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<description>This is SADM Connection</description>
<!-- <description>This component is an example how to use the Customer Adatation 
    Support API. It provides an example on how to develop a new outbound connector.</description> -->

<!-- Skips the enforcer rules from parent pom -->
<properties>
    <enforcer.skip>true</enforcer.skip>
    <cxf.version>2.2.3</cxf.version>
</properties>

<!-- ========================================== = The DEPENDENCIES section 
    ========================================== -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
        <artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId> <artifactId>Test-HTTP-Server</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0.87-SNAPSHOT</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->

    <!-- Jetty is needed if you're are not using the CXFServlet -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId> 
        <version>${cxf.version}</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> 
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId> <version>${cxf.version}</version> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId> <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId> 
        <version>${cxf.version}</version> </dependency> -->
</dependencies>

<build>

    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>META-INF/ra.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.ericsson.mvn</groupId>
            <artifactId>tar-manifest-generator</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <id>CXC1736209</id>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <!-- <plugin> ADDED START <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId> <executions> The m2e eclipse 
            plugin complains but it's valid and works cmd line <execution> <id>copy-dependencies</id> 
            <phase>package</phase> <goals> <goal>copy-dependencies</goal> </goals> <configuration> 
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory> 
            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope> <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive> 
            </configuration> </execution> </executions> </plugin>ADDED STOP -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <raXmlFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/ra.xml</raXmlFile>
                <includeJar>true</includeJar>
                <rarSourceDirectory>target/classes</rarSourceDirectory>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <index>true</index>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>rar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>rar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ant-fix-crlf</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <fixcrlf srcdir="${project.basedir}" includes="*.spec"
                                eol="unix" />
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>Assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.ericsson.mvn
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        tar-manifest-generator
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>build</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

this is the parent pom:-

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
<artifactId>ca</artifactId>
<name>Customer Adaptation</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.125</version>
<description>This component is an example how to use the Customer Adaptation Support API. It provides an example on how to develop a JDV that is distributable, i.e. only active on a fixed set of nodes in a cluster.</description>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/tempRepo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<profiles>  
    <profile>
        <id>buildCAWizard</id>
        <modules>
            <module>Tools/CA-Wizard</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>          
</profiles>

<modules>
    <module>JDV-CUSTOM1-P/JDV-Custom1-Provisioning</module>
    <module>JDV-CUSTOM1-Conf/JDV-Custom1-Conf</module>
    <module>JDV-CUSTOM3-P/JDV-Custom3-Service-Provisioning</module>
    <module>JDV-CUSTOM3-P/JDV-Custom3-Resource-Provisioning</module>
    <module>JCA-CUSTOM3/JCA-Custom3/</module>
    <module>JDV-CUSTOM4-P/JDV-Custom4-Provisioning</module>
    <module>JDV-CUSTOM5-P/JDV-Custom5-VoLTE-Subscriber-View</module>
    <module>DVE-Custom-Cluster-Strategy</module>
    <module>Tools/Test-HTTP-Server</module> 
    <module>Tools/CA-CodeGenerator</module>
    <module>Tools/CA-Wizard</module>
    <module>Assembly_Deployables</module>
    <module>Assembly_SourceCode</module>
    <module>Assembly_Plugin</module>
    <module>Assembly_Repository</module>
    <module>Assembly_CustomAdaptation</module>
</modules>

<properties> <!-- Latest released CF version, should NOT be a snapshot -->
    <common.components.version>2.297</common.components.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!-- ========================================== = The BUILD section ========================================== -->
<build> 
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xsl</include>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.xsd</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>META-INF/**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                                    <target>1.7</target>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <verify>true</verify>
                <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            true
                        </addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-rar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <rarSourceDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</rarSourceDirectory>
                <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-no-snapshots</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireReleaseDeps>
                            <message>!! No SNAPSHOT VERSIONS are allowed when building a
                                delivery !!</message>
                        </requireReleaseDeps>
                    </rules>
                    <fail>true</fail>
                </configuration>
                </execution>

                 <execution>
                    <id>enforce-repository</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <rules>
                        <requireProperty>
                          <property>maven.repo.local</property>
                          <message>You must set a maven.repo.local property to -Dmaven.repo.local=repository</message>
                          <regex>repository</regex>
                          <regexMessage>You must set a maven.repo.local property to -Dmaven.repo.local=repository</regexMessage>
                        </requireProperty>
                      </rules>
                      <fail>true</fail>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <!--plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resolve</goal>
                    </goals>                        
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/myRepo/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>go-offline</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>go-offline</goal>
                    </goals>                        
                    <configuration>
                        <includeGroupIds>com.ericsson</includeGroupIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin-->
    </plugins>
</build>

    <!-- ========================================== 
= The DEPENDENCIES section 
========================================== -->

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>LIB-JDV-Public</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>Utils-PAS</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>API-PAS</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>JavaUtils</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>TEST-Common</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>LIB-PAS</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- ========================================== 
= The DEPENDENCY MANAGEMENT section 
========================================== -->

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>${common.components.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
            <artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>LIB-JDV-Public</artifactId>
            <version>${common.components.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>Utils-PAS</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>API-PAS</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>JavaUtils</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>TEST-Common</artifactId>
            <version>${common.components.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
            <artifactId>LIB-PAS</artifactId>
            <version>${common.components.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://gerrit.epk.ericsson.se:29418/provisioning/prov-ca1.git</connection>
  <tag>ca-1.0.125</tag>
```

Comment: very strange location for a repository: `file:${project.basedir}/tempRepo`

Comment: Your access to Maven Central is not allowed or you have not correctly configured that. `Access denied to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`...Apart from that this project looks very strange in several ways...